# How to pass custom variable as input to nested AWS Step Function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I have two Step Functions, where one (*Step Function 1*) triggers the other (*Step Function 2*).

The first Step Function has as input:

```
{
    "ClusterId": "j-AAAAAAA",
    "CreateCluster": false,
    "TerminateCluster": false,
}
```

My goal is to take the variable **ClusterId** and pass it Step Function 2. This is how did it:

```
        "TRIGGER STEP FUNCTION 2": {
          "Type": "Task",
          "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::states:startExecution.sync",
          "Parameters": {
            "StateMachineArn": "arn:aws:states:us-east-1:312312312312123:stateMachine:STEP FUNCTION 2",
            "Input": {
              "ClusterId": "$.ClusterId",
              }
            }
          }
```

However, the StepFunction 2 input becomes:

```
{
    "ClusterId": "$.ClusterId",
}
```

And NOT:

```
{
    "ClusterId": "j-AAAAAAA",
}
```

Does anyone know how I can pass the **value** of ClusterId to StepFunction 2?

Appreciate the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just figured it out. Instead of:

```
{
    "ClusterId": "$.ClusterId",
}
```

It should have been:

```
{
    "ClusterId.$": "$.ClusterId",
}
```